# Appropriate age for use of electronics

Tags: behavior, discipline, education, age-appropriate, language-development

I was searching for this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmUqE406lo8&t=35s) for the last 3 years.

In it a salesperson refuses to sell a tablet to the parents of a 5 year old saying that they can come back in 7 years and 12 years is the appropriate age.

---

What studies are there on electronics' use (age of introduction) relationships with addiction and socialization (abstinence from socialization); how to interpret those studies as a parent is there an appropriate age (a minimum tolerable or advisable age of introduction to the use of electronics) to introduce the kids to electronics?

Comment: @TimurShtatland Thank you earnestly for your edit. I'd like to (re-)add the education tag and I would like your opinion on this. Socialization is a part of (informal) Education and so is Second Language Acquisition. I would like to stress the (indirect and informal) pedagogical effects of Electronics Use. I also see Discipline as the other side of Education and Behaviour (or the change of it) is the goal of Education and Disclipline. I don't think that Discipline is focused on Punishment and Correcting Behaviour and Behaviour is not a tag focused on specific Behavioural problems.

Comment: Related posts (although they do not answer the question): https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/41385/33055 (shameless plug), and also those tagged with [tag:screen-time] and [tag:programming].

Comment: Thank you pyrotechnical! I appreciate your effort and your edit!

Comment: Thanks for the edit - that helps make it much more on topic. Reopened

Answer (score 4):

That 12 year age would not have been intended as a "no electronics in the house", but more to stop the child having the tablet as their core focus, as that can lead to lack of developmental stimulus. We have various posts on the issues with leaving a toddler or small child unattended in front of a TV or tablet.

But that doesn't mean they should have no access to electronics - especially as the modern world is electronics-based. I would definitely encourage familiarity with electronics well before this 12 years limit. Applications like Facebook restrict usage to those aged 13 and over, but working with children to help them understand online usage, as well as risks and dangers well before that age can help to protect them.

And it can open up interest in career paths in computing, electronics, infosec, etc. See [this question about electronics projects for 5 year olds](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/29508/what-are-age-appropriate-projects-for-5-year-old-interested-in-electronics?rq=1)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131835/discussion-on-answer-by-rory-alsop-appropriate-age-for-use-of-electronics).

Comment: Is the question still opinion-based (in the way defined by the help center). I am directly asking for papers now and for their interpratation as a parent.